# Preventing media to replay

Tags: javascript, cordova

There is an `onClick` event for a link, and I am playing some audio using these lines there:

```
tts = new Media(url, onSuccessTTS, onErrorTTS);
tts.play();
```

However, if user clicks second time on the link before it finishes playing the first media, it plays the same file simultaneously again. Is there any way to prevent playing if the media is currently being played?

There is a callback event for `mediaStatus`, but it is not documented.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the phonegap media api, you are manually creating an audio player.  Therefore you must manage the state of your player programatically.

Since there should be one control for your media player, I would keep the state on the HTML DOM element that has the play button

```
//on click
var $el = $(this); //or $('someselector');

//check if you have already added the playing state to the element
if ($el.data('state') == 'playing') {
    //pause or ignore
} else {
    $el.data('state', 'playing');  //save state on element
    tts = new Media(url, onSuccessTTS, onErrorTTS);
    tts.play();
} // handle stopped if needed
```

BTW phonegap is up to version 2.0, so consider using the [2.0 media api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media).